# Raster reprojection error with gdalwarp

Tags: qgis, gdalwarp

I want to reproject a raster from the rather common EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) to EPSG:5677 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3 (E-N)) :

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:5677 -r near -of GTiff C:/.../raster_og.tif C:/Users/corne/OneDrive/gis/rheinauen/temp/raster_tg.tif
```

However, all I get is the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Too many points (8100 out of 8100) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
```

Here is the complete gdal info of the source file :

```
GDAL command output:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: C:/Users/corne/OneDrive/gis/rheinauen/wsel_hq1_IST.tif

Size is 4437, 8511

Coordinate System is:

GEOGCRS["WGS 84",

DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",

ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,

LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],

PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],

CS[ellipsoidal,2],

AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,

ORDER[1],

ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],

AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,

ORDER[2],

ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],

ID["EPSG",4326]]

Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1

Origin = (3434740.290000000037253,5421087.200000000186265)

Pixel Size = (1.000056344376831,-1.000064622253532)

Metadata:

AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:

INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left ( 3434740.290, 5421087.200) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)

Lower Left ( 3434740.290, 5412575.650) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)

Upper Right ( 3439177.540, 5421087.200) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)

Lower Right ( 3439177.540, 5412575.650) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)

Center ( 3436958.915, 5416831.425) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)

Band 1 Block=4437x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray

NoData Value=nan
```

Comment: Add output of `gdalinfo raster_og.tif`.

Comment: If you look at the corner coordinates 3434740.290, 5421087.200 you can see that the source file can't be in EPSG:4326.

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out too. Thank you anyway